# Wrapping text on Full Calendar month view event bars

Tags: fullcalendar

I am implementing the timeline view of Full Calendar in my project, and although it works and looks great, the only issue I have is that in timeline Month view, the event bars do not wrap so half the text is cut off, especially so when the event only lasts a couple of days.

In Week and Day view, the text wraps fine - it's just in Month view. Is there any way to allow it to wrap the text? In certain cases there are notes added to the booking so they are pretty much unreadable in month view.

I'm using this code to add the description:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.find(".fc-event-title").remove();
    element.find(".fc-event-time").remove();
    if(event.desc) {
        var new_description =
            '<br/><div class="fc-title">' + event.desc + '</div>'
                ;
        element.append(new_description);
    }
}
```

within my calendar params.

Here is a picture of what the entry looks like in timeline Month view:

[image: Month view]

And here is what it looks like in Day view (what I'd like it to look like):

[image: Day view]

If anyone can help with this I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 14):

Just encountered the same problem, and this works for me...

```
.fc-event-time, .fc-event-title {
padding: 0 1px;
white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: legend!!!!!!!!!!!!!! @Michael Emerson please mark as accepted answer if happy. This saved me hours :D

Answer (score 0):

As of fullcalendar.io v6

```
    .fc-event, .event-title {
        padding: 0 1px;
        white-space: normal;
    }
```